# Multi-Line Button text in SWT/WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

Is there any way to force the SWT button text to span two lines, either manually in the SWT code or using the WindowBuilder GUI?
I have this:
[image]

I want something like this (digitally altered image to achieve this):
[image]

Is it possible?  How?

Comment: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg17423.html Try setting it with image although its not advisable to do

Comment: answer below by Monikka by passing `SWT.WRAP` as button style solves the problem for me. e.g. `new Button(parent, SWT.WRAP | SWT.PUSH)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this, is through JNI/JNA. Take note that if you go down this road, you'll be breaking Java's platform independence by calling platform-specific native functions.

For Windows, take a look at the [SetWindowText API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Supposing you have code similar to:

```
Button btn = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
btn.setText("Hello world!");
```

You can obtain the handle via `btn.handle`. With a bit of JNA magic something along these lines might be possible:

```
final User32 lib = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
final HWND hWnd = new W32API.HWND(new W32API.UINT_PTR(btn.handle)
        .toPointer());
final String text = "Hello\nworld!"; // or "Hello\r\nworld!"?
lib.SetWindowText(hWnd, text.toCharArray());
```

I couldn't actually get this to work (it gives a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` on `SetWindowText()` which I couldn't sort out), but this might point you in the right direction.

Comment: It's not the end of the world to me in the current project to accomplish this, and knowing the drawbacks that are involved in accomplishing the task, I'll refrain from the attempt.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: I guess I went a little overkill on that. It seems to me that this approach is the only way to do it using pure SWT.

Comment: This will not work. SWT uses already this function `SetWindowText()`. Windows removes all characters after the first NL, not SWT. That is, unless you set the `ES_MULTILINE` style flag. See my answer for full Java code.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get the multi-line button text work, by adding **SWT.WRAP** as a style for the button and by having '\n' inserted in the text to be set as the button label.

```
....
Button check = new Button(composite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.PUSH );
check.setText("Multi\n Line\n Button \n Text");
....
```

Even though the button.setText(..) java doc says that the button label must not contain new line chars, it works when SWT.WRAP is added as a style('\n' were ignored when SWT.WRAP was not set).

Just thought this could be useful.

[image]

Comment: This is better than my solution with GWL_STYLE. But you still need to overwrite computeSize(). I updated my code to use SWT.WRAP.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of diving into native code, I would do this by creating a custom control. Extend composite, use a label for the multi-line text and add some decoration with 2D drawing. There are methods in graphic context for rounded rectangles and gradient painting. It may not look exactly like a native widget, but, in my opinion, better than using JNI.

Answer (score 4):

The following code does the trick:

```
final int style = OS.GetWindowLong(button.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
OS.SetWindowLong(button.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, style | OS.BS_MULTILINE);
button.setText("line 1\nline 2");
```

You just import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS and that's it. Of course, that class, and the handle field inside button are not part of SWT API, so your code is no longer portable. But the functions are defined in Windows API, so you don't have to worry too much they will change in future versions of SWT.

Be aware that after this change, computeSize() no longer works well.

---

Edit: full class where I take care of computeSize() and GWL style

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;


public class MultilineButton extends Button {

    public MultilineButton(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        final int gwlStyle = OS.GetWindowLong(this.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
        OS.SetWindowLong(this.handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, gwlStyle | OS.BS_MULTILINE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
        final Point size = super.computeSize(wHint, hHint, changed);
        final GC gc = new GC(this);

        final String multiLineText = this.getText();
        final Point multiLineTextSize = gc.textExtent(multiLineText, SWT.DRAW_DELIMITER);

        final String flatText = multiLineText.replace('\n', ' ');
        final Point flatTextSize = gc.textExtent(flatText);

        gc.dispose();

        size.x -= flatTextSize.x - multiLineTextSize.x;
        size.y += multiLineTextSize.y - flatTextSize.y;

        return size;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I implemented this only for \n as line separator. If you want to use \r\n, update the code to convert to single in computeSize.

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting the button text to a string with a '\n' character where you want the line break to happen.

Comment: Read the javadoc carefully for swt button widget. For `setText()` it is clearly mentioned that: `This method sets the button label. The label may include the mnemonic character but must not contain line delimiters.`

Comment: The above comment is correct. It looks like it is not possible to currently do this natively in SWT. The options are to use an image or to use a non-native control. For instance, it is possible to embed Swing controls among SWT ones. Of course, I would consider very carefully whether that's really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

there's actually a super easy way in *swing*, not in SWT. I misread the question when I first posted this answer, but since I found my way here whilst searching for a swing solution, I'll leave it up for others.

```
button.setText("<html>My<br>Text<br>");
```

many swing components render HTML.

On checking the date of posting, not sure if this is a relevant answer to a question that old, but I found this while trying to solve this problem so I thought I'd share. Cheers.

Comment: Note that the question is about SWT, not Swing.

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Apologies.